# как вставить StateIndicatorControl в ячейки GridControl для отображения её значения?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Будет многовато кода, но он простой, без излишеств :)
Мне требуется чтобы в таблице только один из рядов(№3 Статус) но НЕ колонок, отображал свои значения (0 или 1) не в виде числа, а с помощью "лампочки" StateIndicatorControl;
тестовое содержимое таблицы (пардон, не могу её оформить лучше):
ROW_ORDER |PARAMETER_NAME                  |COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4
1          Уровень (%)                      1       2       3       4
2          Скорость (м/мин)                 111     222     333     444
3          Статус                           1       1       1       1

представление таблицы (XAML):

```
<dxg:GridControl  x:Name="cristallizerByStreamsGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding CristallizerStreams}"
         AutoGenerateColumns="KeepOld"  EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True"
         ShowBorder="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  MaxHeight="3000">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn  x:Name="columnRowOrder"        Header="ROW_ORDER" FieldName="ROW_ORDER"       ReadOnly="True"  Visible="False"  />
        <dxg:GridColumn  x:Name="columnParameterName"   Header="Параметр"  FieldName="PARAMETER_NAME"  ReadOnly="True"  />
        <dxg:GridColumn  x:Name="column1"               Header="1"         FieldName="COLUMN1"         ReadOnly="True"  />
        <dxg:GridColumn  x:Name="column2"               Header="2"         FieldName="COLUMN2"         ReadOnly="True"  />
        <dxg:GridColumn  x:Name="column3"               Header="3"         FieldName="COLUMN3"         ReadOnly="True"  />
        <dxg:GridColumn  x:Name="column4"               Header="4"         FieldName="COLUMN4"         ReadOnly="True"  />
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridControl.View >
        <dxg:TableView  x:Name="cristallizerByStreamsGridView"  AllowPerPixelScrolling="True"  AutoWidth="True"  ShowTotalSummary="False"  ShowGroupPanel="False" />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

успешно заполняется из привязанного источника данных; пытаюсь *наколхозить* своё решение просто вручную перебирая ячейки требуемого ряда и перезадавая содержимое ячейки (C#):

```
for (byte columnNumber=1; columnNumber<5; ++columnNumber)
{
    string columnName = (@"COLUMN" + Convert.ToString(columnNumber));
    int rowHandle = cristallizerByStreamsGrid.GetRowHandleByListIndex(2);
    var rowHeader = cristallizerByStreamsGrid.GetCellValue(rowHandle, columnParameterName);//!ТЕСТ, получим заголовок ряда
    var cellValue = cristallizerByStreamsGrid.GetCellValue(rowHandle, columnName);// as decimal?;                   
    var cellElement = cristallizerByStreamsGridView.GetCellElementByRowHandleAndColumn(rowHandle, columnParameterName);
    StateIndicatorControl indicator = new StateIndicatorControl();
    indicator.StateIndex = Convert.ToInt32(cellValue);//цвет лампы
    cristallizerByStreamsGrid.SetCellValue(rowHandle, columnName, indicator);//!исключение
}
```

!исключение: объект не реализует IConvertible -- оно в принципе и ожидалось :) видимо, там должно быть простое значение.
Наверное следует получать ячейку и какой-нить её *визуальный шаблон* править, а лучше заранее это как-то где-то задать, подскажите как это сделать (желательно красиво), или хотя бы что именно загуглить.

PS: если вам покажется, что таблицу лучше развернуть на 90 градусов -- этого делать нельзя, такие *бизнес требования* для отображения данных.

Comment: **1.** Вашими "попытками" вы нарушаете основную суть привязок, а точнее MVVM (код не должен знать об View представление). **2.** Для подобных целей используется либо a) Конвертор b) Доп. свойство в VM. Ну а так, как будет время, могу попробовать набросать пример того, как это сделать, НО не на devexpress (я его ненавижу...), стандартный WPF. Если подойдет - дайте знать, нет - смотрите на пункт 2 и пробуйте сами.

Comment: Плюсую отношение к devX, самые гадкие контролы

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  (1) да :) я оцениваю эту попытку именно саркастически; (2)ясно, спс, попробую реализовать что-то; Увы, мои *бизнес требования* начинаются с DevExpress, мне надо *жрать кактус*

Comment: Судя по постановке задачи, скорее всего здесь не нужны основные фишки GridControl никогда - сортировка, фильтрация, группировка, саммари. Если так и есть, тогда возможно эту задачу правильно решить без GridControl совсем :-)

Comment: @Uranus да, "фишки" не нужны, данные для этого не очень то подходящие и содержимое постоянно по количеству строк/столбцов. `GridControl` выбран в том числе из-за автоматически единообразного представления данных -- возможно лучше без него, как по вашему можно бы это сделать?  

Если например как просто множество текстовых элементов организованные по строкам/столбцам в стек/докпанели -- придётся прописывать привязку каждого элемента к своему отдельному свойству (получаемому под-запросом из общего источника данных), это громоздко и откровенно коряво выглядит  :(

Comment: Я сам с WPF не на "ты", поэтому конкретный ответ не могу дать. Чтобы избежать громоздкости, я бы использовал [Data Templating](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). Во вью модели бы сделал три свойства: Уровенеь, Скорость, Статус. Используя ItemsControl в горизонтальной ориентации, вывел бы список Column1, Column2, Column3 и так далее.

Comment: на самом деле моя основная беда с источником данных -- он сборный, практически каждая строка из другой произвольной таблицы, всё вместе собирается воедино в виде представление(View) на сервере Оракл, в своей программе я получаю его в "привязанную" коллекцию (из которой казалось бы проще всего отобразить данный в `GridControl`, но всё портит одна строчка) и мне обязательно надо их отобразить именно в таком виде а-ля таблица, ориентированная именно так :(